# Firebase Query Snapshot Undefine

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase query to get data from my Realtime Database.
But the **snapshot becomes undefined**.

Exactly everything is running well before growing larger.
This is my code:

```
db.ref('notregis').orderByChild("has_media").equalTo(null).limitToLast(1)
        .once("value", function (snapshot) {
            var key = snapshot.key;
            var data = snapshot.val()[key];
            console.log(key, data);
            console.log('Getting Feed From', key, data.username, index);
            getFeed(key);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your snippet, the snapshot's `key` will be `notregis`, so `snapshot.val()[key]` will likely be undefined.

Instead, you could use the snapshot's `forEach`, which will enumerate the child snapshots (of which there should be a maximum of one):

```
db.ref('notregis')
    .orderByChild("has_media")
    .equalTo(null)
    .limitToLast(1)
    .once("value", function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var key = childSnapshot.key;
            var data = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(key, data);
            console.log('Getting Feed From', key, data.username, index);
            getFeed(key);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Oh Lord, thank you very much. I'm out of caffeine :D